# Virtual number pad in C#- Is there an elegant way to update Textbox.SelectionStart?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, virtual, numpad

I am designing a virtual number pad in Windows Form. Please suppose that I have `Del` key to remove character of `textbox`. When I click on the `textbox` for the first time to select it and then press the `Del` key, the character is removed correctly relative to cursor position. But after updating the content of text, the `SelectionStart` property changes to zero and my blinking cursor disappeared. I solved this problem by saving its value temporarily before updating the content of `textbox` and modifying it at the end.

```
tempSelectionStart = enteredTextbox.SelectionStart; //save SelectionStart value temporarily 
enteredTextbox.Text = enteredTextbox.Text.Substring(0, enteredTextbox.SelectionStart - 1)
                    + enteredTextbox.Text.Substring(enteredTextbox.SelectionStart,
                      enteredTextbox.Text.Length - (enteredTextbox.SelectionStart));
enteredTextbox.SelectionStart = tempSelectionStart-1;
```

I want to know:

1. Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem?
2. How can I hold cursor blinking in the textbox after first time I pressed the key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SelectedText property instead:

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (textBox1.SelectionLength == 0) textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
    textBox1.SelectedText = "";
    textBox1.Focus();
}

private void BackspaceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (textBox1.SelectionLength == 0) {
        if (textBox1.SelectionStart > 0) {
            textBox1.SelectionStart--;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
        }
    }
    textBox1.SelectedText = "";
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: If you want the Del key works as Backspace and delete the character which is placed left side of cursor , only substract one from `SelectionStart`. Is there another way?

Comment: Sigh.  You still use the SelectionText property.

Comment: Dear Passant , can you please guide me to do it by SelectedText property?

Comment: I posted the code, no idea what else you could possibly want.

Comment: Dear Passant, I am grateful of you.